# assign the selected indexpath.row to a variable in another class

Tags: swift

I show the data in `labelTEx` in the table.

When I click `labelTEx`, I open another table class.

I want to transfer the text data of `labelTExt` that I clicked in `UITableViewCell` to `formBaslik` in `DetayViewController`.

that is, I want to transfer the `gifsabaslik [indexPath.row]` that I have selected to the `detayBaslik` in `DetayViewController`. How can I do that?

**DetayViewController**

```
class DetayViewController: UIViewController {
    var formBaslik = String()
}
```

**TableViewController**

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController{
    var gifsayeniresim: [String] = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.labelTExt.text = self.gifsabaslik[indexPath.row]
        cell.labelTExt.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.labelTExt.font  = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 14.0)!
        cell.labelTExt.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell.labelLayout.constant = cell.labelTExt.contentSize.height
        cell.labelTExt.isEditable = false

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(handleTaponTextField(_:)))
          tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
          tap.delegate = self
          cell.labelTExt.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
          cell.labelTExt.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


        return cell
    }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == "newo"{
        if segue.destination is DetayViewController {

               }
    }
```

Comment: Inside `prepare(for segue:)` you can do something like: `if let cell = sender as? TableViewCell, let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {`and then get your data to send to `DetayViewController`

Comment: Why the indexPath? Assigning the actual value would make much more sense.

Comment: in prepare,   vc.formBaslik = gifsabaslik [indexPath.row]    Note: it would be wiser to define formBaslik as String?

Comment: How do I do it? @claude31

Comment: How do I assign the real value? @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @SH Yazilm.  How to do what ?   I will write it in an answer to format code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SH Yasilm
 In DetayViewController, declare

```
var formBaslik = String?
```

In TableViewController, in prepare, write

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
  if segue.identifier == "newo" {
    if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
        // You have clicked in a cell, but that may not have selected it: let's compute its indePath
        let tapPosition:CGPoint = cell.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.table)
        let indexPath = self.table.indexPathForRow(at: tapPosition)

        if let vc = segue.destination as? DetayViewController {
            vc.formBaslik = gifsabaslik[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gifsabaslik[indexPath.row] Error line:  Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'String?.Type'

Comment: What are the elements in `gifsabaslik` ?

Comment: Of course, should correct var formBaslik = String?  into var formBaslik : String?    I assumed that gifsabaslik is declared as [String]

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the indexPath by following the code below.

**In the DetayViewController's very top (below class)**

```
var myStr: String!
```

**Inside the class where you have the tableview**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
if segue.identifier == "newo"{
    if segue.destination is DetayViewController {
        let vc = segue.destination as? DetayViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! YourCellClassName

        vc.myStr = cell.yourString

        //NOTE! If. the cell is a string just do like I did, other way, if that's a textfield/label you should use cell.yourLabel.text
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get the string, not row, I want to send the string value of row

Comment: @SHYazılımGeliştirme Check the edit, tell me if you need more help